# Snap to Face Unavailable

Tags: snapping

Im trying to do Guru's donut series and I'm stuck at the point where you need to snap the icing to face. Instead of snap to face, It gives me two options; snap to face project and snap to face nearest. There is no snap to face option in my drop down menu. Sorry I am new around here and don't know what to do. any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: snap to face unavailable]

Comment: Hi, I don't have snap to face as well, only face project. Maybe the tutorial is with an older version of blender and the names have change. Does snap to face works for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial uses an older version of Blender - I guess you have 3.3, there is this new distinction between *Face Project* and *Face Nearest*.

The difference is that *Face Project* might also snap vertices to hidden/occluded geometry, while *Face Nearest* only snaps to visible geometry.

So in the case of the donut tutorial I guess, if you want to make sure your vertices don't snap to somewhere in the background, it's best to use *Face Nearest*.

From the Blender manual:

- **Face Project**

*Snaps to the face by projecting the current point on the nearest face. This snap mode will snap geometry to both visible and occluded. This snap mode is useful for retopologizing.*

- **Face Nearest**

*Snaps to the nearest surface in world space. This snap mode will only snap geometry to visible (non occluded) geometry.*